# В каких случаях стоит создавать раздельно 2 сайта или совместно - мультисайт?

Tags: wordpress, связывание-данных

Когда стоит использовать плагин типа qTranslateX? На вордпрессовком все сайте будет.

Когда стоит разделить на поддомены, а то и домены разные. Общая суть сайта одинаковая на обоих будет. О себе инфа, контакты, приветственное сообщение какое-нибудь.

Разное - сами записи, их подача и тематика. Приватность некоторых записей будет.

Это не просто перевод содержимого записей на разные языки.

Фото-раздел будет вот одинаковым тоже.

Поэтому никак не решу, стоит ли из-за одних записей создавать две разные копии вордпресс, так же, как и объединять в один, чтобы после не переносить ничего многократно.

Comment: Если содержимое разное, то лучше два раздельных сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Контент разный есть - значит сайты разные. Если вам нужны какие-то общие данные - тогда лучше сделать один сайт как основной, а на другом парсить данные с основного сайта и если такого в базе нет - добавлять.

Даже если сейчас клиент (или может вы себе делаете, просто пока такой необходимости не было) считает что всё остальное будет одинаковым - никакой гарантии, что он не захочет чтобы на одном из сайтов была конкретная фотография, которая будет относиться к конкретной статье на конкретном сайте, а не на обоих.

Мультисайты нужны именно для того, чтобы содержать похожий контент (переводы, филиалы, и т.п.), относящийся к одному и тому же. Думаю, суть понятна.